# How to write own custom jQuery plugin (Uncaught TypeError: ... not a function)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, syntax-error

Where did I make a mistake ? Is that some syntax error ?

custom.js:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.marquee = function(options, callback){

        // check callback
        if(typeof callback == 'function'){
            callback.call(this);
        } else{
            console.log("secound argumnt (callback) is not a function");
            throw "callback must be a function";
            return;
        }

        //set and overwrite default options
        var defOptions = $.extend({
            option1: 10,
            option2: 'something'
        }, options);
    };

    //plugin logic here
    // ...

    return this;

}(jQuery));
//END PLUGIN
```

In same file now i try to run the plugin by calling:

```
// RUN PLUGIN with options or leave empty for defeaults
$.marquee({
    option1: 9,
    option2: 'something else'
}, function(){
    alert('some callback');
});
```

Then I get this error (in chrome console)... anyone knows whats the issue here?:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.marquee is not a function
```

More details about error from the chrome console:

```
(anonymous function) @ custom.js:25m.
Callbacks.j @ jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2m.
Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2m.
extend.ready @ jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2J @ jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2
```

Comment: You created a plugin that works on *elements*, hence you have to select some elements first: `$('div').marquee()`. I recommend to read the jQuery tutorial: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: `$(window).marquee();`

Answer (score 1):

That's because you've attached it to jQuery's prototype, `$.fn`. Your plugin would work right had your code been

```
$('some element').marquee({
    option1: 9,
    option2: 'something else'
}, function(){
    alert('some callback');
});
```

The plugin declared at `$.fn` are plugins that work on *elements* and has their reference of `this` inside the plugin.

The fix is to declare it on `$` or `jQuery`

```
$.marquee = function { 
    // (...) Code here
}
```